# 'float: right' evaluates as 'float: none'

Tags: css, css-float

I have floats that are not behaving, and I have no idea why. This is what the Chrome dev tool says.

[image: google chrome broken float computed view]

As you can see, the only float set is `float: right;`, so it's not a specificity issue.

I've tried setting `width`, changing `display`, explicitly setting `position: static/relative:`, and a few other things I can't recall.

I am at a loss on how to fix it.

Comment: Have you tried using '!important' or setting the float property directly from chrome's style editor?

Comment: @BlažZupančič - Yep, no change.

Comment: Could you please provide the minimal CSS and HTML involved to replicate your issue?

Comment: What kind of HTML element is it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The issue is that the parent was `display:flex;`. You can't float in a flex-box. Hope this helps someone in the future.

Comment: It was a clear and likely possibility that the parent was a flex container. But  you posted very little in the question for us to establish that. Based on the information in your question, we could only guess.

Comment: @Michael_B - Yeah, that was my bad.